# Vue multiples components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm doing a project with ElementUI Tabs (just HTML and JS files, no .vue files) and I want to open a new Tab, and add html inside, like I've always used to do in Jquery and SemanticUI, for example, the user clicks the menu called "Person" and the Person View (a Vue component) opens in the tab (id = "tab1") to add a new person register, and if the user clicks again the "Person" menu, another tab opens (id = "tab2") with the Person View.

First Question: Because the Vue Component has no "el:" selector, how can I tell to component (Person View) to open inside the "tab1", and another click to open inside the "tab2" ? There is any selector like "el" in Vue.component()?

Second Question: Using Vue instance ( new Vue ({options}) ), it works, because is possible to use the selector "el", but I've read before in some blogs, that is not good practice, because the app must have only one instance of Vue. Is correct add more than one Vue instance ( new Vue () )  as used to be done adding many Vue.component ({}) in the project?

Third Question: I've read before that Vue.component() is a Vue instance, and so would be correct to say that Vue.component() and Vue() is the same thing, but with different sintax ?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: 
Actually, a component does have an el.  Your template determines what el is.
For example, I created an inline template for my select2 that look like this:

```
<select2>
    <select></select>
</select2>

Vue.componet("select2", {blah blah blah});
```

in this case el is the select box directly.

If I did:

```
<select2>
    <div>
        <select></select>
    </div>
</select2>
```

the component el would be the div.

Question 2: what you heard from those blogs is nonsense, at least as far as Vue 2 is concerned (never worked with ver 1)
You, as a coder, determine what el is in your code so it is safe to use as a selector. I do it all of the time.

Vues cannot overlap but you can have as many on a page as makes sense. On one set of  my tabs, each tab is completely different from each other and independent of each other so each has its own Vue instance. On another, each tab is the same so a made a single component and generated it inside each tab as part of the parent Vue instance.

question 3:
Think of Components as parts and the Vue instance as the whole containing the parts.  I personally use components to reduce and compartmentalize code. For example, I have a DataTables component, a select2 component and a tab component, in all cases I have a number of each on each page. Then all I need to do is include them in my Vue instance definition.

Comment: Thank You, Bindrid! About 1st Question: The Vue Component documentation says the selector is only the custom tagname, not a CSS Selector like the "el" of Vue Instance does. In the SemanticUI I was creating <div id="p1"> inside the first tab and put the HTML from Person View inside the div, after was created <div id="p2"> inside the second tab and put html, but in your example if I create twice <select2> (without id="s1", id="s2"), how the component will know that must be shown inside the correct <select2>? (In your example there's no id in tag select2, and component has no CSS Selector)

Comment: a component can only act on its own stuff. el in the component will be the top level element in your component.  I don't use ids on my components.  In the case of the select2, the component knows about only its own <select> and does not know about any others, nor does it care about any others.

Comment: If you look at this example on the Vuejs site, you will see they are not using ids either. You will also  see that they are using the el to assign event handlers, etc. https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html

Comment: I understand that component doesn't use any CSS selector, but that is the problem, cause I want to tell to component to be mounted on a specific place, like new Vue () allows through "el" property. Imagine: I put the <selector2> inside two different tabs, and I call an assynchronous function that mounts  component replacing <select2>, if the first call must be mounted in the first <select2> and the second call in the second <select2 >, how can I tell this to component? If the second call returns before the first call, the first <select2> will be replaced by the second call, in the wrong order.

Comment: I discover a $mount() method in the component, and I used it, and I almost got what the I want, but there's a problem:in the first time, the component was not shown in the tab, but in the html I can see that tag <personview></personview> was written inside the tab, and on console appears [Vue warn]:"Cannot find element: personview", but when I click  in the same menu again Person View is shown on the first tab (fields, buttons appears), and in the second tab I can see <personview></personview>. How can I add the component and it be shown on the first time using the $mount("personview")?

Answer (score 0):

After almost two weeks trying, I got it ! 
First i created an object that has a component structure in a JS file
(personview.js) that i load with requireJS, and pass as a parameter to a 
method of Vue Instance called appVue:

```
appVue.addComponent(componentName,{name:"personview",template:"<div>html tags...</div>",methods:...});
```

In appVue i added the method:

```
var appVue=new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data() {
        return {
            components: {},
            instances: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addComponent(componentName,componentBody){
            this.$data.components[componentName]=Vue.component(componentName,Vue.extend(componentBody));
        }
    }
}
```

When the user clicks on menu, the method openViewByClickOnMenu is called 
and executes:

```
methods: {
    openViewByClickOnMenu(){
        //id to identify the components and scripts to load     
        var componentName="personView";  //for this example i forced the name       
        //call a method that adds the new tab, and inside the tab adds 
        //<div id="divX"></div> and return the counter ever increased. 
        //X in id attribute is the number genereate by the counter
        var ctTab=body.addTab({label:menuItem.label});      
        // will be used to identify an instance of compoment
        var componentId=componentName+ctTab;  //will be personView1, personView2, etc..
        // will be used to identify the div where i want to show component
        var divTabId="div"+ctTab;
        //load the personview.js with component body
        requirejs([componentName],function(){
            //creates a new instance of component
            app.$data.instances[componentId]=new app.$data.componentes[componentName];
            //mounts the component in the div that i want
            app.$data.instances[componentId].$mount("#"+divTabId);
        });
    }
```

I think the Vue team could add a method in Vue instance to add 
components dinamically more easily, sometimes there's no need to 
load all html and js files because the user has no acess/permissions 
to see some views. And i miss a way to load html native, like
Angular does, because sometimes we need generate html from template engine
inside a SpringBoot for example.